# Working with dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary that takes data from a file and puts it in list. I want to make a search engine that when I type name or quantity or price of a component it will find all with that name and print info that it holds (price, quantity, category).

**Input**

I just can't make my script read info from lines in the file. The file's text looks like:

```
AMD A4-3300 2.5GHz 2-Core Fusion APU Box|5.179,00 din|58|opis|Procesor
AMD Athlon II X2 340 3.2GHz Box|4.299,00 din|8|opis|Procesor
INTEL Celeron G465 1.9GHz Box|3.339,00 din|46|opis|Procesor
INTEL Celeron Dual Core G550 2.6GHz Box|1.439,00 din|13|opis|Procesor
```

**Output**

Here is my code  which should be a search engine for my components, I just don't know how I can take form list  data and target that data full info for example I type key word like AMD and seach engine print all AMD components that have AMD in their name or price I put price range and I got all prices in that range. I tried some things but it wont work.Sorry for long time to respond.I translated my code, there may be some lines left out but I hope you get the picture.

```
def option_p_components():

option = 0
#component = []
components = []
while option == 0 :
    option_comp = option_p_components_str()
    option_k = int(raw_input("Chose option : ")
    print "" \
          ""

    if option_k != 1 and option_k != 2  :
        error = "!!!Error!!!"
        error_p = " you typed wrong command please try again  ."

        print "-" * 80
        print error.center(80)
        print error_p.center(80)
        print "-" * 80

        option = 0

    if option_k == 1 :
        option_p_d = 0
        print "Components search "

        print"-" * 80

        cu = temp_comp(components)
        print cu

        print "X)Working with components(editing, deleting )"
        print"-" * 80
        print "1)Change components "
        print "2)Editing components"
        print "3)Delating componetns"
        print "4)Components search "
        print "5)Back"
        print"-" * 80
        option_p_d = int(raw_input("Chose option :"))

        if Option_p_d == 2 :
            option_d = 0

            for I in range(5):

                u_component_name = raw_input("Unesite naziv komponente :")
                u_component_price= raw_input("Unestie cenu komponente:")
                u_component_quantity = raw_input("Unesite kolicinu komponente :")
                u_component_opis = raw_input("Unesite opis komponente :")
                u_component_category = raw_input("Unesite kategoriju komponente:")

                component = {"name_compo":u_komponenta_ime,
                              "price":u_komponenta_cena,
                              "quantity":u_komponenta_kolicina,
                              "opis":u_komponenta_opis,
                              "category":u_komponenta_kategorija}

                upis_komponente = saving_components(component)
                components.append(saving_components)


                print"-" * 80
                print "1)New component"
                print "2)Back"
                print"-" * 80

               option_d = int(raw_input("Odaberite opciju :"))

                if option_d == 1 :

                    option_k = 0

                elif option_d == 2 :

                    option_p_komponenti()

    elif option_k == 2 :

        print "Back"


def saving_components(component):

final_komponenta = component["name_compo"] + "|" + component["price"] + "|" + componenta["quantity"] + "|"\
                 + component["opis"] + "|" + component["category"]

file = open("Data/component.txt", "a")
file.write(final_component)
file.close
```

def reading_component(component):

```
file = open("Data/component.txt", "r")
for line in file :

    name_comp, price, quantity, opis, category = line.split("|")

    komponenta = {"name_compo": name_comp,
                  "price": price,
                  "quantity": quantity,
                  "opis" : opis,
                  "category": category}

    # ovo izvlaci samo pojedinacne vrednosti iz recnika
    compon_info = "Name: " + component["name_compo"] + "\n" + "price: " + component["Price"]+"\n" +\
                      "Quantity:" + component["quantity"] + "\n" + "Opis: " + komponenta["opis"] + \
                      "\n" + "category: " + component["category"] + "\n"

    #print compon_info
    component.append(component)
    #print sortiranje(kompon_info)
    #print sorted([compon_info])
    #print compon_info.sort()
    #Vrti koliko ima u fajlu for ...a to je 7


file.close()
return component 

def temp_comp(components):
    pretraga_po_opisu(komponente)

def pretraga_po_opisu(komponente):
    kolicina = str(raw_input("Unesite kolicinu:"))
    for komponenta in komponente:

    if komponenta["kolicina"] == kolicina:
        print komponenta["kolicina"]
    return None

def pera(komponente, cena):
ulaz = input("Unesi")
list = komponente.pera("cena",cena)
```

Comment: You will need to come up with a Regular Expression to tokenize each line. Then you can parse each line based on that. Once you have tokens, populating the dictionary will be trivial.

Comment: Could you show your file read code? Cannot help with this only

Comment: @Cyber -- A regex seems a bit overkill for this don't you think?  Once you have the line, it looks like a simple `line.split('|')` would work...

Comment: @mgilson Yes you are right, I didn't look at the format of each line that carefully. He very well could simply split on '|' for this problem.

Comment: @mgilson: or even `csv.DictReader(fileobj, ('name_compon', 'price', 'quantity', 'something_else', 'category'), delimiter='|')`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Yep.  That would even give him the option of quoting if necessary.  the tricky part is that it appears that there are 5 fields and OP only wants to keep 4 ;-).  I suppose that we'd need to use `itemgetter` on the result if we knew *which* 4 OP wanted. :)

Answer (score 2):

All you need is [`csv.DictReader()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) together with a sequence of key names for each column:

```
with open(inputfilename, 'rb') as fileobj:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fileobj,
        ('name_compon', 'price', 'quantity', 'something_else', 'category'), 
        delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

where `row` is the dictionary you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look into using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), you could always use it here:

```
component_dicts = []
components = ("name_compon", "price", "quanity", "category")
with open('/path/to/data') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        components_dicts.append(dict(zip(components, line.split("|")[:4]))) 
        #slicing the first four elements because you never say which 4 out of 5 you wanted.

for c in components_dict:
    print c
```

Here the `line.split("|")` method is creating a list of `str`'s, dividing the string being read wherever the `"|"` character is found.

Then [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) will return a `list` of `tuples` which you then feed into a `dict`:

```
# This is what it would look like after you zip the components tuple and the line.split("|") data
[(name_compon, 'AMD A4-3300 2.5GHz 2-Core Fusion APU Box'), (price, '5.179,00 din'), (quanity, 58), (type, opis)]
```